# Magento invoice status always set paid

Tags: magento-1.7, orders, invoice, order-status, status

When a invoice is created out of an order the status of the invoice is always set on paid.
Ofcourse, when an online payment is made the order should be set on paid but with a check money or bank transfer it should be an other status. Any ideas how to configure this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it:

Set the following variables of your payment method to true:

```
protected $_canCapture                  = true;
protected $_canCapturePartial           = true;
```

Comment: Any idea for a Magento 2-solution?